# binary_search & upper_bound

Tags: binary-search, upperbound

I want to convert all the ones in the following boolean array into zeroes using binary_search and upper_bound. But it isn't working. Can someone help me out with this??

**Here's my code:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
    vector<ll> hv;
    for(ll i=0;i<10;i++)
        hv.push_back(i%2);
    while(binary_search(hv.begin(),hv.end(),1)){
        vector<ll>::iterator it = upper_bound(hv.begin(),hv.end(),0);
        ll ind = it - hv.begin();
        hv[ind] = 0;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```